# Boxcox in R gives a closure error in the dataframe

Tags: r

I have a simple code:

```
library(MASS)
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-datasets/master/insurance.csv")

b <- boxcox(lm(df$charges ~ 1))
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in df$charges : objeto de tipo 'closure' no es subconjunto
```

That seems strange to me. I tried checking the `lm` call inside and it works fine. I can `summary` it and its working, however, trying to apply the `boxcox` function to select `lambda` is giving this error

Comment: Do you use boxcox to asses your variable distribution or your residuals distribution? Btw, boxcox is very controversial

Answer (score 0):

```
boxcox( charges ~ 1, data = df, lambda = seq( -0.25, 0.25, length = 10 ))
```

[image: plot of boxcox]